# Using the Spark Kinesis connector to connect to a specific shard

Tags: spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I'm using KinesisUtil to consume a Kinesis stream in a Spark application. The code example I'm working with makes as many 'createStream' calls as the number of shards on the Kinesis Stream.

Is there a way to have KinesisUtil connect to a specific shard instead? I am implementing a design that requires specific Spark nodes processing events from specific shards.

Thanks,
Ranjit

Comment: Shard is only a capacity unit in a Kinesis stream, it shouldn't be part of your design. If you need events to be processed together, use the same partition key for them.

Comment: My events are indeed partitioned by the producer and an event always comes through a single shard. 

I want the Spark consumer application to process events from only a single shard. At the moment, using KinesisUtil.createStream will cause the application to connect to all shards in that stream and that is not desirable. Bullet 4  of this design document (http://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-1.1.0-rc2-docs/streaming-kinesis.html) suggests that KinesisUtil can spin up more than one KinesisRecordProcessor to consume multiple shards. I want it to only connect to one shard.

Comment: The producer is not aware of the number of shards that you have in your stream. It only provides the partition key and kinesis knows to which shard to put it to. You can split and merge shards without your producer awareness of any change on its side.

I'm still not sure I understand what is unique with this specific shard (that you want only to read it)?

Comment: I Think you are trying to achieve this thing but its still under development so it isn't in the Spark library till now. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/kinesis-using-sdk-java-get-data.html